# Checking asp.net label properites with jquery function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have simply asp.net label which is bound in code behind in `Page_Load()` function.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="text"></asp:Label>
```

I write jquery function which checks whether the label is empty. This function is fire on `asp:button` onclientclick.

```
function confirmationAccept() {
    var g = $("#<%=text.ClientID%>").val();
    if (g.length > 0) {
        confirm("Accept?");
    }
    else
    {
        confirm("or not?");
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it does not work. Line with `var g` seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label does not have `.val()`, you need to use `.text()` of `.html()`

```
var g = $("#<%=text.ClientID%>").text();
```

Also make sure jQuery is added before you use it.

Comment: I try this but confirm box still are not fired.

Comment: Can you show us code of confirmation button and generated html?

Comment: but still I have a problem with length properties which returns always 0

Comment: You do not have text for label so getting length 0, <asp:Label runat="server" ID="text">abc</asp:Label> would give you 3

Comment: I bound this label in pageload method but I also try like you and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please use html() and val() in jquery function.

```
function confirmationAccept(){
var g = $("#<%=text.ClientID%>").html();
if(g.length>0){
confirm("Accept?");
}else{
confirm("or not?");
return false;
}
}
```